# image viewing website in php ideas and where to start at?

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php and I want to create a dynamic image viewing webiste. The idea of the website is to have image on every page with next and back button. Every time the user click the next button I want a it create a new page with the new picture that is loaded from my web server according to the new page. Any Ideas where to start and what are some additional techniques I need to know to accomplish this ?

additional details: I want to create the page dynamically according to a function.

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how to ask questions on SO, and what questions are suitable. Your questions is overly broad.

Comment: You realize why you're being downvoted, right? Maybe the best move would be to go on amazon.com and search for "php for beginners" since stack overflow is more of a site to help solve programming problems, not necessarily outline a project or do your work for you. With how vague this question is, <?php //code here ?> is a correct answer. See the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code of the page

```
<img src="<?php echo basename($_GET['image'])?>">
```

call it

```
image.php?image=tits.jpg
```

with image name you want to show.
that's all

Sorry, no functions.

Comment: lol you should just serve tits.jpg no matter what the get var is cause that's all anyone wants to see.